# SSRS Report Export to Excel Doesn't Show Wrapped Text

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I have an SSRS Report that has data in a column containing line breaks (CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)) however it refuses to show the wrapped text automatically or by choosing from the Home toolbar Cells-->Format-->Auto fit row height.  Does anyone know how to make this happen so the user can see the cell contents when it opens in Excel?  Basically they have to manually select each row and specify a height.

Comment: What version of SSRS are you using? Does it look OK on screen before you export? I may be wrong but I'm sure I've had reports like this in the past and then have not been a problem (although my memory is getting bad these days!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SQL 2012 for the moment.  I also tried the same report on 2019 and it makes no difference.  The report is hooked into an app so it comes out directly as EXCEL.  When I run it from the report server in HTML it is showing the data with the multiple lines as desired.